# Parse.com combine nested query

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, subquery

I am new to using parse, and currently adding parse to an app that uses SOAP web services to replace them.

Now I come a little stuck, as due to having it done in MySQL and php I am trying to translate the logic from the tables and code to parse.

I have a function that I have written and it achieves exactly what I am after, however I just think its wrong and can be done better, for starters I am not calling findObjectsInBackground, which I know I need to.

I am trying to take this result and then reload a tableView.

```
NSMutableArray *activityfeed = [NSMutableArray new];
//get current user
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

if (user != nil) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
    //get event that user is involved in
    [query whereKey:@"invited" equalTo:user];

    //get the events
    NSArray *events = [query findObjects];


    //loop over the events
    for (PFObject *event in events) {

        //owner is a pointer to the users class
        PFUser *owner = event[@"owner"];
        if (![user.objectId isEqualToString:owner.objectId]) {
            //ignore the info for the logged in user for now

            //invited is a relation so one event has many users
            PFRelation *relation = [event relationForKey:@"invited"];
            PFQuery *query = [relation query];
            [query orderByDescending:@"dateinvited"];
            [query addDescendingOrder:@"dateaccepted"];

            //get the friends that are involved with the event
            NSArray *friends = [query findObjects];

            for (PFUser *friend in friends) {//Perform logic checks here and then add to activityfeed}


        }

    }
}

return activityfeed;
```

So my logic above gets the current user, then get all the events that user is involved with, then get all the other people involved with that event and then work out what to display.

Is there a more efficient way of doing the above?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use `whereKey:matchesQuery` in cases like this. Take some research on this.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836456/ios-swift-parse-collect-data-from-3-classes) may help you find out some solution.